# ElasticSearch query text

Tags: elasticsearch

My index data is

```json
    {
      "full_name":"Edwin Powell Hubble",
      "job": "IT"
    }
    {
      "full_name":"John Edwin",
      "job": "Accountant"
    }
    {
      "first_name":"Eric Petterson",
      "job": "Accountant"
    }
```

I am not sure if anyone could help me to build a query to get data that have `full_name` as `Edwin`. It tried with `term` query seem not really work.

Comment: You should specify what do you expect to get from this query, do you want string to contain `Edwin` or be exactly equal to `Edwin`, case sensitivity and such.

Comment: Thank @Filip Yes I want to search any record that has full_name with `Edwin` inside.   Maybe it is related to my mistake when I did index the data and not analyzed the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `full_name` can be of any length and should be analyzed when indexed, I believe you have mapped the attribute as of type `text`.

For the same reason I also believe you will have requirements to return results as 'Edwin Powell Hubble' and 'John Edwin' when searched with 'Edwin' and return 'Edwin Powell Hubble' when search with 'Edwin Pow'

[match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) should help you with these use cases.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "full_name": "Edwin"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) to get data that have `full_name` as `Edwin`

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "full_name": "edwin"
    }
  }
}
```

**[Term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) works on exact text match, so you will not get any document for `Edwin` since there is no data in your sample index data that have a match for `full_name` as `Edwin`**

Comment: @Sokmesa Khiev Do you expect to get the first two documents i.e `"Edwin Powell Hubble"` and `"John Edwin"` ?

Comment: Yes to get all records that full_name have `Edwin`

Comment: I use  "match_phrase_prefix" and it works well. That field should be analyzed when indexed. Big thank for your support